# My android tablet is not working

Tags: applications

My android tablet is displaying an error message 'Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped'. The message occurs so quickly that I am unable to touch any application.

Comment: tabloid, huh? :p Have you tried booting into Recovery Mode (hold down Power + Volume buttons)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Quickly press OK on the error dialog so you can follow the rest of the steps.
2. Navigate to **Settings > Apps > All**.
3. Scroll down to **Phone** and click it.
4. **Clear cache** for it. If the problem persists, **clear data** as well.

If this does not help, try clearing cache and data for the **Sim Toolkit** app as well.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know to fix this problem is to restore to factory settings in Settings-Backup&Reset.

Comment: If you suggest that, you should a) provide a reason why it should help, and b) name the implications (here: all user-installed apps and all data will be gone after that).

Comment: Oh, apart from that, your proposed solution cannot work for the OP. Question says: *The message occurs so quickly that I am unable to touch any application.* So no chance to reach that menu.

Answer (score -2):

Recovery mode > factory reset and
Clear cache

Comment: If you suggest that, you should a) provide a reason why it should help, and b) name the implications (here: all user-installed apps and all data will be gone after that).